# Parsing HTML table structure with no class attributes

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I realize there are a lot of questions already asked about using BeautifulSoup to parse tables in HTML, but try as I might I can't get any of the general solutions offered to correctly parse this website. Run out of ideas for what I could do to get there, so I decided to post another one.

Question: How to correctly parse unclassified html tables where columns are grouped in a 'td' structure.

This is the web page: http://www.abyznewslinks.com/costa.htm.

The first thing to note that there are pretty much nothing but tables on that page. Every header is its own table. The table with actual information can be distinguished by the fact that they have urls in them  with other domain names than abyznewslinks. It's useful to keep the interspersed 'subheader' rows around, so I'm planning on having those just end up as single values in a row in a csv.

I understand the general principle here. The soup response can be queried with find_all('table'), resulting in a list of lists where every list is a table. Every table has a 'tr' structure which has multiple 'td' structures nested within, and a 'row' in the 'tr' consists of the first element in every 'td'

What I've been unable to do is convert that into actual code. Web scraping is something I'm not very familiar with, so I apologize if the solution is obvious to someone experienced with BS.

My output so far is a list where all the items of every 'td' get bundled together, which is a step forward from the initial result, but not necessarily in the right direction. That code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.abyznewslinks.com/costa.htm"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table')

records = []
columns = []
for tab in table:
    for tr in tab.find_all("tr"):
            trs = tr.find_all("td")
            record = []
            for each in trs:
                try:
                    link = each.find('a')['href']
                    text = each.text
                    record.append(link)
                    record.append(text)
                except:
                    text = each.text
                    record.append(text)
            records.append(record)
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to "tie" the rows together.

For example:

```
import requests
from itertools import zip_longest
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag


url = 'http://www.abyznewslinks.com/costa.htm'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for tr in soup.select('table')[4:-1]:
    tds = []
    for f in tr.select('font'):
        tds.append([])
        for c in f.contents:
            if isinstance(c, NavigableString) and c.strip():
                tds[-1].append(c.strip())
            elif isinstance(c, Tag) and c.name == 'a':
                tds[-1].append([c.text, c['href']])

    for column in zip_longest(*tds, fillvalue=''):
        print(column)

    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
('Costa Rica Newspapers and News Media - National',)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Costa Rica - Broadcast News Media',)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('National', ['Columbia', 'https://columbia.co.cr/'], 'BC', 'GI', 'SPA', 'Radio')
('National', ['Monumental', 'http://www.monumental.co.cr/'], 'BC', 'GI', 'SPA', 'Radio')
('National', ['Multimedios', 'https://www.multimedios.cr/'], 'BC', 'GI', 'SPA', 'TV')
('National', ['Repretel', 'http://www.repretel.com/'], 'BC', 'GI', 'SPA', 'TV')
('National', ['Sinart', 'http://www.costaricanoticias.cr/'], 'BC', 'GI', 'SPA', 'Radio TV')
('National', ['Teletica', 'https://www.teletica.com/'], 'BC', 'GI', 'SPA', 'TV')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Costa Rica - Internet News Media',)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('National', ['A Diario CR', 'http://adiariocr.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['AM Costa Rica', 'http://www.amcostarica.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'ENG')
('National', ['AM Prensa', 'https://amprensa.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['BS Noticias', 'http://www.bsnoticias.cr/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['Costa Rica News', 'https://thecostaricanews.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'ENG')
('National', ['Costa Rica Star', 'https://news.co.cr/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'ENG')
('National', ['Costarican Times', 'https://www.costaricantimes.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'ENG')
('National', ['CR Hoy', 'https://www.crhoy.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['Delfino', 'https://delfino.cr/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['El Guardian', 'https://elguardian.cr/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['El Mundo', 'https://www.elmundo.cr/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['El Pais', 'http://www.elpais.cr/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['El Periodico CR', 'https://elperiodicocr.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['Informa Tico', 'http://informa-tico.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['La Prensa Libre', 'http://www.laprensalibre.cr/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['NCR Noticias Costa Rica', 'https://ncrnoticias.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['No Ticiero', 'http://no.ticiero.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['Noticias al Instante Costa Rica', 'https://www.noticiasalinstante.cr/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['Noticias Costa Rica', 'https://noticiascostarica.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['Q Costa Rica', 'http://qcostarica.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'ENG')
('National', ['Tico Deporte', 'https://www.ticodeporte.com/'], 'IN', 'SP', 'SPA')
('National', ['Today Costa Rica', 'http://todaycostarica.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'ENG')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Costa Rica - Magazine News Media',)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('National', ['EKA', 'https://www.ekaenlinea.com/'], 'MG', 'BU', 'SPA')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Costa Rica - Newspaper News Media',)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('National', ['Diario Extra', 'http://www.diarioextra.com/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['La Nacion', 'https://www.nacion.com/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['La Republica', 'https://www.larepublica.net/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA')
('National', ['La Teja', 'https://www.lateja.cr/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Costa Rica Newspapers and News Media - Local',)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Alajuela',)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Alajuela', ['El Sol', 'https://elsoldeoccidente.com/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA')
('Alajuela', ['La Segunda', 'http://www.periodicolasegundacr.com/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA')
('Grecia', ['Mi Tierra', 'http://www.periodicomitierra.com/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA')
('San Carlos', ['La Region', 'http://laregion.cr/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA')
('San Carlos', ['San Carlos al Dia', 'https://www.sancarlosaldia.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('San Carlos', ['San Carlos Digital', 'https://sancarlosdigital.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Cartago',)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Cartago', ['Cartago Hoy', 'http://www.cartagohoy.com/'], 'IN', 'IG', 'SPA')
('Paraiso', ['Brujos Paraiso', 'http://www.brujosparaiso.com/'], 'IN', 'IG', 'SPA')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Guanacaste',)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Bagaces', ['Guanacaste \na la Altura', 'https://www.guanacastealaaltura.com/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA', 'TV')
('Filadelfia', ['El Independiente', 'https://diariodigitalelindependiente.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA', 'Radio')
('Liberia', ['Canal 5 Guanacaste', 'http://www.canal5guanacaste.com/'], 'BC', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('Liberia', ['Guana Noticias', 'https://guananoticias.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('Liberia', ['Mensaje', 'https://www.periodicomensaje.com/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('Liberia', ['Mundo Guanacaste', 'http://www.mundoguanacaste.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('Liberia', ['NTG Noticias', 'https://ntgnoticias.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('Liberia', ['Radio Pampa', 'http://www.radiolapampa.net/'], 'BC', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('Nicoya', ['La Voz de Guanacaste', 'https://vozdeguanacaste.com/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('Nicoya', ['Voice of Guanacaste', 'https://vozdeguanacaste.com/en'], 'NP', 'GI', 'ENG', '')
('Tamarindo', ['Tamarindo News', 'http://tamarindonews.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'ENG', '')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Heredia',)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Flores', ['El Florense', 'http://elflorense.com/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA')
('Heredia', ['Fortinoticias', 'http://fortinoticias.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Limon',)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Limon', ['El Independiente', 'https://www.elindependiente.co.cr/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA')
('Limon', ['Limon Hoy', 'https://www.limonhoy.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Puntarenas',)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Paquera', ['Mi Prensa', 'http://www.miprensacr.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
('Puntarenas', ['Puntarenas Se Oye', 'https://www.puntarenasseoye.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('San Jose',)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('Acosta', ['El Jornal', 'http://eljornalcr.com/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA', 'TV')
('Goicochea', ['La Voz de Goicochea', 'https://www.lavozdegoicoechea.info/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA', 'TV')
('Perez Zeledon', ['Canal 14', 'http://www.tvsur.co.cr/'], 'BC', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('Perez Zeledon', ['Enlace', 'https://www.enlacecr.com/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('Perez Zeledon', ['PZ Actual', 'http://www.pzactual.com/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('Perez Zeledon', ['PZ Noticias', 'http://www.pznoticias.org/'], 'IN', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('San Jose', ['Diario Extra', 'http://www.diarioextra.com/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('San Jose', ['El Financiero', 'https://www.elfinancierocr.com/'], 'NP', 'BU', 'SPA', '')
('San Jose', ['Extra TV', 'http://www.extratv42.com/'], 'BC', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('San Jose', ['La Gaceta', 'http://www.gaceta.go.cr/gaceta/'], 'NP', 'GO', 'SPA', '')
('San Jose', ['La Nacion', 'https://www.nacion.com/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('San Jose', ['La Republica', 'https://www.larepublica.net/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('San Jose', ['La Teja', 'https://www.lateja.cr/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
('San Jose', ['Tico Times', 'http://www.ticotimes.net/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'ENG', '')
('Tibas', ['Gente', 'http://periodicogente.co.cr/'], 'NP', 'GI', 'SPA', '')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That is beautiful Andrej - great answer. And looks very generalizable for this kind of thing by just messing around with the slicing you did to drop the header and footer tables. +1 would give you way more if I could!

Answer (score 0):

I understand even less, including python, so my solution may seem stupid.
English from google translator

After "text = each.text" try to separate generically, something like:

```
text.split("<br>")
```

And there doesn't seem to be much to do, as the site was made in a very inconvenient way.